# Grouping of Grouped Data and iterating through each grouped data in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Team,

Need your help in grouping data in XSLT.

Requirements:

1. Group data based on report_number
2. Group step 1 output data based on program_name
3. Iterate through each of grouped data and create XML as in expected output

I am able to execute first two steps. I am not able to arrive at a logic 
for step 3.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MTR>
    <program>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>1</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Portfolio Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>1111111111</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>1111111111</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>1</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Portfolio Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>2222222222</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>2222222222</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>1</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Customer Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>3333333333</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>3333333333</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>1</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Portfolio Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>4444444444</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>4444444444</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>1</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Relationship Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>55555555555</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>55555555555</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
        <program_row>
            <report_number>2</report_number>
            <program_id>PMP</program_id>
            <program_name>Ringo Manager Program</program_name>
            <ssn_tin>6666666666</ssn_tin>
            <acct_number>6666666666</acct_number>
            <total_value/>
        </program_row>
    </program>
</MTR>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MTR>
<reports>
    <report>
        <report_number>1</report_number>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <prog_name>Portfolio Manager Program</prog_name>
                <acct_no>1111111111,2222222222,55555555555</acct_no>
            </header>
            <header>
                <prog_name>Customer Manager Program</prog_name>
                <acct_no>3333333333</acct_no>
            </header>
            <header>
                <prog_name>Relationship Manager Program</prog_name>
                <acct_no>4444444444</acct_no>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </report>
    <report>
        <report_number>2</report_number>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <prog_name>Ringo Manager Program</prog_name>
                <acct_no>6666666666</acct_no>
            </header>           
        </headers>
    </report>
</reports>
</MTR>
```

Incomplete XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="kGroup" match="program_row" use="report_number"/>
    <xsl:key name="progNameGroup" match="program_row" use="program_name"/>

    <xsl:template match="MTR">
        <MTR>

            <xsl:copy-of select="emb_disc" />

            <xsl:copy-of select="emb_foot_note" />

            <reports>
            <xsl:for-each select="program/program_row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kGroup', report_number)[1])]">
                <report>

                    <headers>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('kGroup', report_number)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('progNameGroup', program_name)[1])]">
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('progNameGroup', program_name)">
                                <header>
                                    <prog_name></prog_name>
                                    <acct_no></acct_no>
                                </header>                                       
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>     
                    </headers>
                </report>       
            </xsl:for-each>
            </reports>

        </MTR>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correction, you need to make sure the second-level key includes the value of the first-level key and then you need to output the items:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="kGroup" match="program_row" use="report_number"/>
    <xsl:key name="progNameGroup" match="program_row" use="concat(report_number, '|', program_name)"/>

    <xsl:template match="MTR">
        <MTR>

            <xsl:copy-of select="emb_disc" />

            <xsl:copy-of select="emb_foot_note" />

            <reports>
            <xsl:for-each select="program/program_row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kGroup', report_number)[1])]">
                <report>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="report_number"/>
                    <headers>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('kGroup', report_number)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('progNameGroup', concat(report_number, '|', program_name))[1])]">
                            <header>
                                <prog_name><xsl:value-of select="program_name"/></prog_name>
                                <acct_no>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="key('progNameGroup', concat(report_number, '|', program_name))/acct_number">
                                        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </acct_no>
                            </header>                                                                  
                        </xsl:for-each>     
                    </headers>
                </report>       
            </xsl:for-each>
            </reports>

        </MTR>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKx9.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer. I wanted to integrate this logic and test exhaustively before accepting. It worked like a charm.